# Wordpress - how to replace <!--more--> with string on the_content() in single.php

Tags: php

I want to add text on a single wordpress blog post page where the "read more" text would usually be inserted.  However, I can't configure a plugin to replace that text.  I tried a few different sources, but I'm having trouble finding the solution.

After looking through https://stackoverflow.com/questions/887447/wordpress-plugin-finding-the-more-in-the-content and the page it links to, I still haven't been able to find a solution to this.

Comment: Its still not clear what you want to do.

Comment: This belongs to Wordpress.SE

Answer (score 1):

what version are you using? in wp 3.0 above you can use

```
<?php the_content( __( 'Continue reading <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', twentyten' ) ); ?>
```

Comment: I'm using 3.2 - I'd like to insert an javascript for an adsense text ad where <!--more--> usually goes on the posts.  I'm not sure this code will allow me to do that, but I'm going to test now.

Answer (score 1):

see: ['Adsense Ad at the More Tag Position'](http://www.transformationpowertools.com/wordpress/adsense-ad-at-more-tag-fold)